# IIS 7 Manage Allowed IP Range for a Website from an External File

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a doozy of a problem. I have an IIS7 website hosted on a Windows SBS 2008 server that can only be accessed from a list of 3000 or so IP addresses. Is there a way I can input this list of IPs via a text file? Using the GUI to do it seems like a nightmare scenario. I know for Apache there is a .htaccess file that can be used for this. Is there an equivalent in IIS7?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method that exists for this purpose, but I'd imagine if you know a bit of .Net programming you could automate the interface with Microsoft's UIAutomation library.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.